# Angular JS Clear Input field function

Tags: angularjs, scope

I want to clear an input field on button click, but I want to have a function in controller for it.

So I use

```
<div ng-click="emptyInput('filter')">clear</div>
```

And then a function

```
$scope.emptyInput = function(elemName){
    $scope.elemName = null;
}
```

but it does not work, because it clears $scope.elemName that does not exist at all. How can i tell to use function parameter as name after $scope.  ?

Comment: `$scope[elemName] = null;`

Comment: Pass the property you want to clear as the parameter to emptyInput e.g. emptyInput(filter) and set the value of the parameter to null in the function e.g. function(prop) { prop = null; }

Comment: can skip the function also and do `ng-click="filter=null"`